# How to disable caching in asp.net webform globally

Tags: asp.net, caching

Is there any way to disable caching in webforms, I cannot have code with me. I have a webconfig. in that is there a way to disable caching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put  this in application `beginrequest`

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 3):

For the whole project :

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";


Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");


Response.Expires = -1;
```

or for a specific page:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```